# SpringBootApplication failed to load properties from application.yml file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

Configuration class,

```
@Configuration
public class SpringContext {
@Bean
public BlockingQueue<String> queue(@Value("${queue.size}") int queueSize) {
    return new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
   }
}
```

Main class,

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringContextTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication(SpringContext.class);
        springApplication.setWebEnvironment(false);
        springApplication.run();
        System.out.println("queue.size" + System.getProperty("queue.size"));
    }

}
```

application.yml,

```
queue.size: 10
```

While starting the main class I'm getting the following error,

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${queue.size}"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
```

**I'm I missing some annotations** ?, In my understanding I've used the minimal annotations required for a spring boot application.
I have seen some similar posts but didn't helped. Also
tried with **--spring.config.location**.

My Spring starter version: **1.3.6.RELEASE**

Answer (score 3):

Your config file looks more like an `application.properties` rather than an `application.yml`

```
queue.size: 10
```

The equivalent `yml` should be:

```
queue:
    size: 10
```

**UPDATE**

Yes both should work in `.yml` you are right. I replicated exactly your example and it worked!

Just make sure you `application.yml` file is in the root of the `src/main/resources/`. I had the same error as yours when I had the `application.yml` file in a subdirectory e.g. `src/main/resources/com/myapp/`

Answer (score 1):

The [Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) section of the Spring Boot docs, explains all the details that you might need.

As per your example to load properties in the main class you can do something like this,

1. First double check the location of the yaml file, It should be located in /src/main/resources/application.yaml
2. The content should be like the following example,

   ```
   app:
       value1: 12
       value2: stringValue
   ```
3. Sample code,

   ```
   package com.demo;

   import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
   import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
   import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

   @SpringBootApplication
   public class App {

   public static void main( String[] args ){
       SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(App.class);
       Environment env = app.run(args).getEnvironment();

       String value1 = env.getProperty("app.value1");
       String value2 = env.getProperty("app.value2");

       System.out.println("---------------- "+value1);
       System.out.println("---------------- "+value2);

   }


   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

#### Guesses

According to the current information you provides, I can't re-produce the problem, so the following is just some guesses:

- Check whether file name and file location of `application.yml` is right;
- Try use Spring EL:

  ```
  @Value("#{applicationConfig['queue.size']}")
  ```
- Try debug property loading:

  ```
  @Bean
  public BlockingQueue<String> queue(ConfigurableEnvironment env) {
    return new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(); // set breakpoint here, to see if env has your property in PropertySource: applicationConfig
  }
  ```

#### More

More about [property source and yaml loading](http://tonyz93.blogspot.com/2017/09/spring-boot-customize-environment.html) in my blog.

#### Further

If the suggestions not help, you may better

- provide a sample project that can re-produce problem;
- provide complete stacktrace;